# Core Data test fixture fails to load into the DB correctly

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, xctest

I am testing my core data objects by first setting up a full core data stack in memory then tearing it down again for every test.

For some tests I set up some related objects in the set up method then go ahead and test their interaction with them. After everything working fine for a long time now that I'm hitting close to 400 test cases random ones are beginning to fail. Individually they all pass.

After a lot of debugging I have found that sometimes a property on one of my fixtures doesn't get set correctly. I know that in most cases it does get set.

To consistently see the bug happening I have copied the test 20 or so times - renaming each one. Sure enough every run of the suite now results in at least one or two of the cases failing.

Is there some way I can ensure my fixtures are set up correctly? Is there some issue with core data that doesn't play well with rapidly setting up and tearing down stores?

- I don't want to put sleeps in my tests - too slow.
- I don't want to have an on disk db - too slow.
- I don't particularly want to check for the property being set correctly or not for this particular test class as thats not scalable.

Xcode 5.1.1, XCTest

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in sleeps to see if that fixes the problem? That could tell you whether you are dealing with a performance limitation with Core Data. Could you be running out of memory?

Comment: Yes I do believe it was something to do with this - sleeps helped a bit but I really don't want to have to do that. For the time being I have modified my tests to load far less data into the db on setUp. I'm testing slightly less code but my suite is far more stable. May come back to this problem when I have more time.